# How to use svg in image src attribute?

Tags: image, svg

I would like to use this svg:

```html
<svg height="30" width="200">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">⚡</text>
</svg>
```

as a src attribute in image. How can I do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you have a separate SVG file with that code that you want to display on your HTML page? Do you want to include the SVG code itself in your HTML file?

Comment: Even no, I just have emoji (copy text), and I would like to some how use this in img tag

Comment: So you just want to have an `<img>` tag that displays the emoji, without having a separate file?

Comment: Thats right, or some how we can convert this emoji to svg, then pass to img tag?

Comment: If you have a separate SVG file, you can do `<img src="myFile.svg">` just like you would with any other image format. If you don't want to make an extra file, you can use a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme): `<img src="data:image/svg+xml,<!-- your SVG code here -->">`. Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

Just convert it to a [data url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), remembering that it now needs valid namespaces.

```html
<img src='data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" width="200">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">⚡</text>
</svg>'>
```

Comment: And escape **#** (like in colors) with ``&23;``

Answer (score 3):

External SVG files **must** have the correct SVG namespace declaration to be recognised by the browser.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" width="200">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">⚡</text>
</svg>
```